# How to delete a collection matching a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, sql-delete

I would like to delete all posts associated to every user of my application matching a determined condition. In particular I would like to delete all posts older than 30 days only if a user has more than 20 posts.
At first I wrote the following code:

```
users = User.all
users.each do |user|
    if user.posts.any? && user.posts.count > 20
        user.posts.delete_all('created_at < ?', 30.days.ago)
    end 
end
```

However, looking at the [API documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionAssociation/delete_all), method `delete_all` for collections does not imply the records are actually removed from the database, and that depends precisely on the specified parameter, `:nullify` or `:delete_all`

Therefore, considering that method `delete_all` for collections requires one of the above parameters, would the following code be correct:

```
users = User.all
users.each do |user|
    if user.posts.any? && user.posts.count > 20
        user.posts.where('created_at < ?', 30.days.ago).delete_all(:delete_all)
    end 
end
```

or am I expected to use something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify the `:delete_all` flag only when you define your association with the `:nullify` flag.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, dependent: :nullify
end
```

Otherwise `:delete_all` is implied.

One other important point is that `delete_all` ignores the callbacks that you might have defined. If you want to have the callbacks called, you need to use `destroy_all`.

`destroy_all` doesn't care about the `dependent` flag.

Comment: What kind of callback can be involved here? The only callbacks I use are in controllers. In the posts controller for the destroy action there is a before_action :correct_user callback. But my code is part of a background job, non user is involved. Is delete_all still a good choice?

Comment: Your ActiveRecord models might have callbacks like `before_destroy`.